# Getting an API key on Web of Science

Tags: web-of-science

I am trying to use "Web of Science API Expanded" or "Web of Science API Lite" for my search. I have managed to log on to the developer website and register an application. Now there comes the step where I should subscribe the application to one of the available APIs by clicking on a subscribe button. This step is supposed to be the last one on the path leading me to an API KEY.

However, when I navigate to the preferred API's information page from my application, I see the sections "Api Settings" and "Description" but no "Applications" section! Hence, no Subscribe button and no API KEY! Any suggestions on how else to get my Application subscribed or get an API KEY?